# WPF disable anti-aliasing of Text when using RenderTargetBitmap at other than 96 DPI

Tags: c#, wpf

after hours of trial and error I need your help!

I am attempting to create a image files that represents WPF controls, but I need all text/graphics to be Aliased (i.e. not Anti-Aliased).  I need the image to be created with a DPI higher than the default of 96.0 as the text quality is insufficient for my need at that level.

Whenever I render the image using `RenderTargetBitmap` using a DPI other than 96.0 then the Text is anti-aliased and I am not able to prevent it.  Rendering at 96.0 DPI the text is not anti-aliased and displays correctly - but not at a sufficient quality level.

The rendering code:

```
namespace TestRenderBitmap
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

    public partial class RenderTargetBitmapTestWindow
    {
        public RenderTargetBitmapTestWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdRender_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var requiredDpi = 96.0;
            SaveToPngStream(controlToRender, requiredDpi);
        }

        public void SaveToPngStream(FrameworkElement control, double targetDpi)
        {
            var encoder = EncodeControlToImage(control, targetDpi);
            using (var filestream = new FileStream("output.png", FileMode.Create))
                encoder.Save(filestream);
        }

        private BitmapEncoder EncodeControlToImage(FrameworkElement control, double targetDpi)
        {
            var bmp = GetBitmapFromControl(control, targetDpi);
            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder { Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.Off };

            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
            return encoder;
        }

        private RenderTargetBitmap GetBitmapFromControl(FrameworkElement control, double targetDpi)
        {
            const double screenDpi = 96d;

            var height = control.ActualHeight; 
            var width = control.ActualWidth;
            var dv = new DrawingVisual();

            using (var ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
            {
                var br = new VisualBrush { Visual = control };

                ctx.DrawRectangle(br, null, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
            }
            var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(width / screenDpi * targetDpi), (int)(height / screenDpi * targetDpi),
                targetDpi, targetDpi, PixelFormats.Default);
            bmp.Render(dv);
            return bmp;
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML code for this is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" x:Name="controlToRender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10.667" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="33,41,55,56" Text="Hello World" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="22,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107"/>
    </Grid>

    <Button x:Name="cmdRender" Content="Render" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="cmdRender_Click" Margin="0,0,10,10" />
</Grid>
```

at 96.0 DPI I get an image (zoomed) that looks like this:
[96DPI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRRTc.png)

at 192DPI this image looks like this:[192DPI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pARKh.png)

Comment: 10.667 point text is much larger than that.  You are not actually rendering the text at 192 dpi, you are rescaling the bitmap.  So you see the graphics interpolation artifacts.  Hard to imagine that is intended, but you'd be looking for RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode() to get NearestNeighbor interpolation.

Comment: Hans, thanks for your reply, I don't understand your comment about the Point size of the font.  But I agree that the issue appears that the image is being scaled, and not created at the requested DPI.  I thought the `DrawingVisual` should render at the specified DPI of the target bitmap, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have previously attempted a number of ways using the `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(bmp, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);` on the Bitmap (like this one), the drawing visual and the control without any effect.